# Should I use the modular-pattern when writing a nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Now a days it's some what customary to use the [modular pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) when writing javascript on the web. But it's rarely that I see this approach when looking at nodejs modules distributed on npm. Is there way that nodejs differs from the javascript implementations on the web that makes the use of the modular pattern redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's no good reason to. The reason wrapping your code in `(function () {` and `})();` is useful is that browser JavaScript executes on a global scope. Node.js, on the other hand, "sandboxes" code to it's own file and only shares code via the `module.export` system. (you can also modify a `globals` object, but you're evil if you do)

Comment: Yes... But it's not completely sandboxed since you can make a variable global by omitting the var definition. This is on the other hand expected.